# Java EmbeddedDatabase (H2) logging

Tags: java, h2, embedded-database

I would like to change the logging of my EmbeddedDatabase. Atm every time I open a connection it logs "... Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to ...". In my test suite, I open for every request a new connection, and now there are way too many of these messages.

```
EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .generateUniqueName(true)
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .build();
...
Connection connection = embeddedDatabase.getConnection();
```

I didn't find any kind of log level. I just can set the PrintWriter. But I wanna see the error msgs.
I run this outside of spring as a regular unit test.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://h2database.com/html/features.html#trace_options ?

Comment: Not exactly what I needed, but you put in the right direction (see my answer). Thx

Answer (score 1):

It seem like the getConnection method from the EmbeddedDatabase and from the DriverManager create a different log strategie for the connection. The default config fits for my problem. So the code would look like this:

```
new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setName("test")
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .build();
...
Connection connection = DriverManager
       .getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test", "sa", "");
... or
Connection connection = DriverManager
       .getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=3", "sa", "");
```

More options:
https://h2database.com/html/features.html#trace_options